# I cannot inject the PasswordEncoder class because of the JWTTokenProvider

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-security, dependency-injection, jwt

I am writing a REST MVC application. I'm using Spring Boot and Hibernate. For protection, I decided to add Spring Security and JWT to the project.

I use `BCryptEncoder` to encode the password. Accordingly, I have it in the `JWTTokenProvider` class as a bean. I need to inject `PasswordEncoder` into the `UserService` class, but I can't. I understand the reason, but I don’t know how to fix it.

`UserSevice`:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Service
public class UserService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    private final UserMapper userMapper;

    private final PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;


    public UserDTO registration (RegistrationUserDTO registrationUserDTO){

        User user = new User();

        user.setName(registrationUserDTO.getName());
        user.setLastName(registrationUserDTO.getLastName());
        user.setLogin(registrationUserDTO.getLogin());
        user.setMail(registrationUserDTO.getMail());
        user.setPassword(passwordEncoder.encode(registrationUserDTO.getPassword()));
        user.setRole(Role.CUSTOMER);

        userRepository.save(user);

        return userMapper.userToUserDTO(user);
    }
}
```

`JwtTokenProvider`:

```java
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@Component
public class JwtTokenProvider {

    // Fields
    //
    private final UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Value("${jwt.token.secret}")
    private String secret;

    @Value("${jwt.token.expired}")
    private Long validityInMilliSeconds;


    // METHODS
    //

    @Bean
    public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
    }


    @PostConstruct
    protected void init() {
        secret = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(secret.getBytes());
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param login
     * @param role
     * @return ТОКЕН
     */
    public String createToken(String login, Role role) {

        Claims claims = Jwts.claims().setSubject(login);
        claims.put("roles", role.name());

        Date now = new Date();
        Date validity = new Date(now.getTime() + validityInMilliSeconds);

        return Jwts.builder()
                .setClaims(claims)
                .setIssuedAt(now)
                .setExpiration(validity)
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS256, secret)
                .compact();
    }


    public Authentication getAuthentication(String token) {
        UserDetails userDetails = this.userDetailsService.loadUserByUsername(getLogin(token));
        return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userDetails, "", userDetails.getAuthorities());
    }


    public String getLogin(String token) {
        return Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token).getBody().getSubject();
    }


    public boolean validateToken(String token) {
        try {
            Jws<Claims> claims = Jwts.parser().setSigningKey(secret).parseClaimsJws(token);

            return !claims.getBody().getExpiration().before(new Date());

        } catch (JwtException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
            throw new JwtAuthenticationException("JWT token is expired or invalid");
        }
    }


    /**
     *
     * @param req
     * @return bearerToken
     */
    public String resolveToken(HttpServletRequest req) {
        String bearerToken = req.getHeader("Authorization");
        if (bearerToken != null && bearerToken.startsWith("Bearer ")) {
            return bearerToken.substring(7);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

`JwtUserDetailsService`:

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserService userService;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userService.findByLogin(login);

        JwtUser jwtUser = JwtUserFactory.create(user);
        log.info("IN loadUserByUsername - user with login: {} successfully loaded", login);
        return jwtUser;
    }
}
```

Logs:

```java
2020-08-20 11:59:44.964  WARN 15396 --- [           main] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'securityConfig' defined in file [D:\JetBrainsProjects\Coffeetearea\build\classes\java\main\ru\coffeetearea\config\SecurityConfig.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtTokenProvider' defined in file [D:\JetBrainsProjects\Coffeetearea\build\classes\java\main\ru\coffeetearea\security\jwt\JwtTokenProvider.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtUserDetailsService' defined in file [D:\JetBrainsProjects\Coffeetearea\build\classes\java\main\ru\coffeetearea\security\JwtUserDetailsService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 0; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'userService' defined in file [D:\JetBrainsProjects\Coffeetearea\build\classes\java\main\ru\coffeetearea\service\UserService.class]: Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 2; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCurrentlyInCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jwtTokenProvider': Requested bean is currently in creation: Is there an unresolvable circular reference?
2020-08-20 11:59:44.964  INFO 15396 --- [           main] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Closing JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
2020-08-20 11:59:49.500  INFO 15396 --- [         task-1] j.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean : Initialized JPA EntityManagerFactory for persistence unit 'default'
Exception in thread "task-2" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationNotAllowedException: Error creating bean with name 'delegatingApplicationListener': Singleton bean creation not allowed while singletons of this factory are in destruction (Do not request a bean from a BeanFactory in a destroy method implementation!)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:212)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:207)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.retrieveApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:245)
    at org.springframework.context.event.AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.getApplicationListeners(AbstractApplicationEventMulticaster.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.java:134)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:404)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.publishEvent(AbstractApplicationContext.java:361)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.publishEventIfRequired(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:99)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher.access$100(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:50)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataSourceInitializedPublisher$DataSourceSchemaCreatedPublisher.lambda$postProcessEntityManagerFactory$0(DataSourceInitializedPublisher.java:200)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2020-08-20 11:59:49.525  INFO 15396 --- [           main] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
2020-08-20 11:59:49.532  INFO 15396 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown initiated...
2020-08-20 11:59:49.589  INFO 15396 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-1 - Shutdown completed.
2020-08-20 11:59:49.598  INFO 15396 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Stopping service [Tomcat]
2020-08-20 11:59:49.628  INFO 15396 --- [           main] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2020-08-20 11:59:49.659 ERROR 15396 --- [           main] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   : 

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

The dependencies of some of the beans in the application context form a cycle:

   securityConfig defined in file [D:\JetBrainsProjects\Coffeetearea\build\classes\java\main\ru\coffeetearea\config\SecurityConfig.class]
┌─────┐
|  jwtTokenProvider defined in file [D:\JetBrainsProjects\Coffeetearea\build\classes\java\main\ru\coffeetearea\security\jwt\JwtTokenProvider.class]
↑     ↓
|  jwtUserDetailsService defined in file [D:\JetBrainsProjects\Coffeetearea\build\classes\java\main\ru\coffeetearea\security\JwtUserDetailsService.class]
↑     ↓
|  userService defined in file [D:\JetBrainsProjects\Coffeetearea\build\classes\java\main\ru\coffeetearea\service\UserService.class]
└─────┘



Process finished with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are injecting something, the `JwtTokenProvider` in an `@Configuration` class that produces a bean that is needed by the `JwtTokenProvider`. So the `JwtTokenProvider` needs something provided by the security configuration while the `SecurityConfig` can only be created when it has a `JwtTokenProvider` hence a circular dependency.

Remove `@Component` from the `JwtTokenProvider` and create an `@Bean` method in the `SecurityConfig` (or whatever it is called) which creates the `JwtTokenProvider`.

It is also not recommended to use `@Bean` methods in `@Components` so move that to the `SecurityConfig` as well.

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

  @Bean
  public BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(8);
  }

  @Bean
  public JwtTokenProvider jwtTokenProvider(UserDetailsService userDetailsService) {
    return new JwtTokenProvider(userDetailsService);
  }

  // other config
}
```

Now there probably still is an issue as your `JwtUserDetailsService` needs the `UserService` which needs the `PasswordEncoder` and this again creates a circular reference. You might be better of injecting the `UserRepository` into your `JwtUserDetailsService` and use that to get the user by the login. I'm assuming that the `UserService` simply delegates to the `UserRepository.findByLogin` method.

```java
@Slf4j
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class JwtUserDetailsService implements UserDetailsService {

    private final UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String login) throws UsernameNotFoundException {

        User user = userRepository.findByLogin(login);
        if (user != null) {
          JwtUser jwtUser = JwtUserFactory.create(user);
          log.info("IN loadUserByUsername - user with login: {} successfully loaded", login);
          return jwtUser;
        } else {
          throw new UsernameNotFoundException("Unknown user '"+login+"'");
        }
    }
}
```

**NOTE:** Your `UserDetailsService` didn't honour the contract (no user found should throw an `UsernameNotFoundException`. The modified one does honour that contract.